# FIFO Ruby Queues algorithm not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Build the now_serving method which should call out (i.e. puts) the next person in line and then remove them from the front. If there is nobody in line, it should call out (puts) that "There is nobody waiting to be served!". When I try to use the shift method to get rid of the first element in the array. I end up with the wrong output. Here is the Ruby code:

```html
def now_serving(array)
  while array.length != 0
    array.each do |name|
      puts "Currently serving #{name}."
      array.shift
      end
  end
    puts "There is nobody waiting to be served!"
end
```

But the array.shift is only working once, How do I get it to drop the first element of an array continuously. Here is the code for the Rspec:

```html
describe "#now_serving" do
    context "there are no people in line" do
      it "should say that the line is empty" do
        expect($stdout).to receive(:puts).with("There is nobody waiting to be served!")
        now_serving(katz_deli)
      end
    end

    context "there are people in line" do
      it "should serve the first person in line and remove them from the queue" do
        expect($stdout).to receive(:puts).with("Currently serving Logan.")
        now_serving(other_deli)
        expect(other_deli).to eq(%w(Avi Spencer))
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to shift an array at the same time you loop through it.

```
def now_serving(array)
  while name = array.shift
    puts "Currently serving #{name}."
  end

  puts "There is nobody waiting to be served!"
end
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when I run the code. ``` Failure/Error: now_serving(other_deli)
     
       #<IO:<STDOUT>> received :puts with unexpected arguments
         expected: ("Currently serving Logan.")
              got: ("Currently serving Avi.") - @chumakoff

Comment: What are `katz_deli` and `other_deli`? Where are these from?

Comment: these are some tests from Rspec. @chumakoff

Comment: The Rspec file is given to tests the code from an online educational source. https://github.com/learn-co-curriculum/deli-counter This link shows the instructions to follow.@chumakoff

Comment: Sorry, have no time for this

Answer (score 0):

So this fixed my bug

```html
def now_serving(array)
  queue = Queue.new
  queue = array
    
    if array.length > 0
    puts "Currently serving #{array[0]}."
    array.shift
    else
    puts "There is nobody waiting to be served!"
    end
end
```